# How do I find a phrase within a folder in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to search for a word or phrase inside a folder from VS Code. I don't find a way to specify folder I want to search

[image]

Comment: Just the folder name is sufficient in the `files to include` input or right-click the folder name in the explorer file tree and choose `Find in Folder...` and that folder path will be properly populated in the same `files to include` input.

Answer (score 0):

Specify a path in the files to include box.

```
foldername\*.*
```